# How to properly use sed in foreach loop

Tags: bash, shell

How to properly use `sed` in `for` loop? I want to loop through an array and each loop, open a file `template.txt`, do spring replacement and output result to a file. For example:

```
values=( "val_1982" "val_1985" "val_1987" )

for i in "${values[@]}"
do 
    sed -e "s/\${VAL_ID}/$i/" \
    -e "s/\${ENTRY}/"local"/" template.txt > outputfile_$i.txt
done
```

But I get:

```
bash: template.txt: command not found
bash: template.txt: command not found
bash: template.txt: command not found
```

The output files are created but all empty.

Comment: your script looks fine (except for the comma's in your values list). Are you running the command inside the directory where template.txt is to be found?
If you want ot understand what is happening; you might run your script with the `-x` flag: `bash -x script.sh`. then you see all the commands as they are executed by bash.

Comment: without the comma, same issue. But thanks for correcting the comma, it was a mistake while typing in SO

Comment: Are you sure it is the code you show which is creating the error?  I can't reproduce it running this code.  One way to reproduce would be to have an unescaped newline after the `sed` command and before the `template.txt > outputfile_$i.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced with this and it worked:

```
for i in val_1982 val_1985 val_1987
do 
    sed -e "s/\${VAL_ID}/$i/" \
    -e "s/\${ENTRY}/"local"/" template.txt > outputfile_$i.txt
done
```

Comment: Changing from an array to a list does not explain the error.